# Laravel 5.2 migration comment on column in migration

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing a project with laravel 5.2 . I have a question, I created a migration file to change the column's comment. But according to the doc, it said "column modifiers" is used when you are adding a column. So I don't know how to update an existing column's comment, someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `comment()` method along with `change()`

```php
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name')->comment('Name of the user')->change();
});
```

To make sure it migrated properly

```
mysql> show full columns from users like 'name';
+-------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------------------+
| Field | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment          |
+-------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------------------+
| name  | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references | Name of the user |
+-------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.